# PhantomJSDriverTimes Out On Button Click Event in Selenium

Tags: vba, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I have VBA code in Excel that is supposed to login to a website and download some files using Selenium. I have my code working using the `ChromeDriver` and am trying to modify it to work with the `PhantomJSDriver` so I can do something else while the program runs (it runs for ~45 minutes). The issue is that when I try to have Selenium click on the login button I get a timeout error:

```
Run-time error '101': 
WebRequestTimeout: 
No response from the server within 30000 seconds
```

The interesting thing is that after it times out, I can use the immediate window to take a screenshot and it's clear that the button was clicked and the browser has advanced to the next page.

```
Dim D As New PhantomJSDriver

With D
   .ExecuteScript ("window.resizeTo(1920,1080)")
   .SendKeys MyKeys.Control, "0" 'Set zoom to 100% (causes errors if not 100%)
   .Get "LoginPage.com"
   .FindElementByName("username").SendKeys "UserName"
   .FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[@class='centreContent']/form[@id='loginForm']/input[@id='passwordDummy']").Click
   .FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[@class='centreContent']/form[@id='loginForm']/input[@id='password']").SendKeys "Password"

   .TakeScreenShot.SaveAs "C:\Users\110SidedHexagon\Downloads\Capture.png" '<---Takes screenshot of login screen with uesername and password filled in
   .FindElementByName("loginSubmitButton", 0.1).Click '<---Error occurs here
   <--Using the immediate window taking a picture after the error breaks code execution shows login was successful-->
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that after the button is clicked, the new loaded page doesn't return a completed state within 30 seconds.
It could be due to a dead resource within the page.

You could try to increase the server timeout:

```
Dim driver As New PhantomJSDriver
driver.Timeouts.Server = 60000  ' 60 seconds
driver.Get "https://..."

driver.FindElementByName("loginSubmitButton").Click
```

Or you could define a timeout to load the page and skip the error:

```
Dim driver As New PhantomJSDriver
driver.Timeouts.PageLoad = 20000 ' 20 seconds
driver.Get "https://..."

On Error Resume Next
driver.FindElementByName("loginSubmitButton").Click
On Error Goto 0
```

To get the latest version in date working with the above example:
https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/latest